My socks shrunk after 1 wash - what to do
I got a whole bunch of new socks, but after 1 wash they have shrunk a lot. Like they were soft and stretchy, now they are crazy tight and I have to stretch them out a lot so that they are abble to fit over my heel. What is the cause of this, how can I undo it, and how do I wash and dry my socks without them shrinking and losing the stretchiness and softness?

Next time, use the recommended wash and dryer programs.
